# How to put a layout on top of layout.setZOrderOnTop()

Tags: android

I've a SurfaceView for a book for pagecurl.
I wanted it to be transparent for some reasons and I've used

```
myView.setZOrderOnTop()
```

to achieve it. Till now, everything is working perfectly.

Now I need to put some views (suppose an ImageView) on top of this surfaceview (book). When I do so, the imageview is hidden behind the book. The part of it that is outside book bounds, is visible as expected. I've added the imageview in last of XML but don't find a way to change the z order of imageview so that it becomes visible on book.

Please suggest me a way to achieve this.

*NOTE: I can't remove setZOrderOnTop() unless there is any other solution to make my surface view transparent.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know your code but hope it will help you:

```
view1.setZOrderOnTop(false);        
view2.setZOrderOnTop(true);
view2.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

In my case:

[image]

Try to play with this,

see reference of `setZOrderMediaOverlay` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Actually I had another issue which I thought is because of the method **setZOrderMediaOverlay()**

Actually, my *loadBitmap()* method of *SurfaceView.PageProvider()* sub-class is giving index==length of array. That was causing the app crash.

But thanks a lot, for helping :)

Comment: Also works to add an overlay (button) to the android webview native video view (ContentVideoView)

Comment: we don't have setZOrderOnTop for button method available.

Answer (score 1):

I have a VideoView with a View over it in xml.

For me, the solution was

`videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)
videoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)`

Comment: this works like charm , also it solve the issue of black screen when video view visible.