# How to set background white color for surfaceview and left the fab visible

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I need to draw some scene with white "fog of war". I did in init method:

```
setZOrderOnTop(true)
holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
```

That works but my fab-s (floating action buttons) is under of surface view. How can i do they visible?

Some screenshot:

[image: fab-s]

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/a/18762491/5909412

Comment: @P.Juni this block of buttons is simple view group. it does't have methods for change zOrder

Comment: yes but I can see that you use some `setZOrderOnTop(true)`. Why ? Maybe change it to `false`

Comment: "fog of war" will be black. i need white